# Self disposing class

Tags: c#, dispose, invoke

I have a class that manages a process. When calling `Stop()` or `Dispose()` on this class, it will first send TCP command to the process to ask it to close itself, then check back in 1 second time, if it's not close, call `CloseMainWindow()`, then wait another seconds, if it's still running, call `Kill()`.

Now I have a `List<>` of this class to manage a bunch of processes. When I would like to remove them from the list, I would manually call `Dispose()`, then `Remove()`. I want to make sure that I called `Dispose()` before I loose the only reference. Since calling `Dispose()` will take at least 2 second to return, it will take a while if I have say 5 items to be removed.

So I intended to have another function called `SafeDispose()` which `Invoke()` `Dispose()` then return. Now removing these from the list and calling `SafeDispose()` instead of `Dispose()` will be immediate while the classes itself disposing themselves slowly.

Is it advisable to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you are suggesting, leaving Dispose "as is" and instead having a helper method that tears down the object asynchronously - which is attached to the object.

Is it advisable?

**Perhaps**, the tricky thing about introducing threads is all the threading mess that comes with it.

- What happens when another method accesses the object when it is asynchronously disposing?
- What happens when another AsyncDispose is called concurrently?
- How are errors propagated?
- Will this introduce deadlocks?
- Will running lots of disposes on different threads (and different objects) cause any issues? (like running out of tcp sockets)

If you can answer all in a satisfactory way then maybe.

Keep in mind you could also spin off a thread in the UI that handles all expiration and does so in a single thread (as another option)

Comment: Well the class is internal and only use by myself. And once removed from the list, there's no more reference to it, so there's no chance of having called AsyncDispose again, that avoids the concurrency issue, and deadlock. Each of the process managing class lasted at least 10 seconds to few hours, closing them only takes fraction of a second, and I won't have more than 10 of them at a time, so thread count should be on safe level. When it's time to kill, error is not critical in this case, and the process will close itself automatically if the tcp connection closes. Btw, this is a non UI class

Answer (score 0):

Use an event instead

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MyClass c = new MyClass())
        {
            c.Disposed += MyClass_Disposed;
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to dispose");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void MyClass_Disposed(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I've been disposed");
    }
}


class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler Disposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.Disposed != null)
            this.Disposed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to impose an event on a class when there's no need for it. You essentially "hard wired" a callback onto the Dispose method.

Comment: @Sleeper. I think you read my answer before I edited it. The event is not imposed.

Comment: I don't see the point in this solution. Firing event is also a block method, so it still need to wait.

Comment: @Sleeper. If he calls Dispose() asynchronously then he doesn't need to wait. His class just need to notify it's finished.
Even Microsoft does this way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.disposed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use asynchronous method invoke to dispose the objects then remove them from the list.

Say you have a list of class foo to dispose called **foos**.

```
var iars = new List<IAsyncResult>();
Action<IDisposable> disposeAction = a => a.Dispose();
foreach(var foo in foos)
    iars.Add(disposeAction.BeginInvoke(null, null));
foreach(var iar in iars)
    disposeAction.EndInvoke(iar);
foreach(var foo in foos) foos.Remove(foo);
```

If you on .net 4.0, you can do this with the Parallel library for more effeciency.
Edit - popular demand for List.Remove thread safety.
As for exception safety. Dispose() method should never throw exception in the first place.

Comment: The class shouldn't care about removing itself from a list. It neither shoud know about that list existence. Abstraction.

Comment: Eh, actually it doesn't. Asynchronous method is done **outside** the foo object.

Comment: While I agree with the general approach, there are two problems with the code: 1) Thread safety issues (`List<T>.Remove`) and 2) Exception safety (an exception thrown from `BeginInvoke` would crash the process). A better solution would be to invoke `Dispose` from a `Task`, wait on all the tasks, and then remove them from the list.